# Get 'page' number with infinite scroll

Tags: theme-development, loop, plugin-jetpack

I added infinite scroll support of the Jetpack plugin to my own theme using [this tutorial](http://jetpack.me/support/infinite-scroll/):

```
add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
    'container'  => 'content',
    'footer' => false,
    'render' => 'vividflow_infscroll_render',
    'wrapper' => 'post_summaries',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'type' => 'scroll'
) );
```

Now I need something like a counter which increments every time additional posts are loaded.

I know that the new posts are placed in an `infinite-view-`*`n`* class and I have a JavaScript function which I want to call on that new loaded class:

```
function setupPostSummaries(counter) {
    jQuery('.infinite-view-'+counter).doSomething();
}
```

So I guess I need a PHP variable in the infinite scroll render function or the loop which increments every time additional posts are loaded. Then I can do in the end of The Loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setupPostSummaries(<?php the_counter(); ?>);</script>
```

Is such a variable there already? Or is there an other way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Comment: @kaiser oh, sorry I didn't reply. Your answer works good, but I wait with accepting and rewarding so that others can reply as well.

Comment: Fully ok for me. Btw: I edited some minor things, as `numberposts` is deprecated. Added a replacement.

Comment: I saw - didn't even notice it. But see you in 20 hours!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Grabbing the values

Normally you just access the `$wp_query` object or, in case you did do a custom query like `$my_query = new WP_Query();`, the `$my_query` object. From there you can get the `$wp_query->numberposts` (or better, as non-deprecated: `$wp_query->found_posts`) for the full amount of posts and `$wp_query->posts_per_page` for the number of posts per page.

### Inside a plugin

Just write a small plugin to do this job for you:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Infinite Scroll Counter Script */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse88834_add_script' );
function wpse88834_add_script()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpse_counter',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/counter.js',
        array( 'jquery' ), // the infinte scroll script should also be added as dependency
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'js/counter.js' ),
        true
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wpse_counter',
        'wpse_counter_obj',
        array(
            'numberposts'    => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->numberposts,
            'found_posts'    => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts,
            'posts_per_page' => $GLOBALS['wp_query']->posts_per_page,
        )
    );
}
```

When you're then inside your script, you can access your data there easily

```
/* Inside ~/js/counter.js */
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    /* wpse_counter_obj.numberposts */
    wpse_counter_obj.found_posts
    wpse_counter_obj.posts_per_page
    // Current
    var post_count_curr = 0;
    post_count_curr  += wpse_counter_obj.found_posts;
    console.log( post_count_curr  );
} );
```

Now you just have to add an event listener to the infinite scroll and increment the counter.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this same issue, and used the following to get the page number:

```
$curPage = (get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) + 1;
```

I cannot say why its off by one when doing a custom WP_Query yet its fine if I don't - this may be something specific to the theme I'm customizing.  But this value does increment for each call.

Comment: Please explain how this will help with content loaded viea Javascript. Where are you suggesting this code be placed?

Comment: The content is still rendered server side, javascript is just making the request.

Comment: This is still an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to *the problem* of only affecting the last set of posts, but not to *the question* of getting a 'page number', is here:

All new posts are loaded in a div with class `post_summaries`. You can edit your JavaScript function so that it only affects the last element with this code:

```
function setupPostSummaries() {
    jQuery('.post_summaries').last().doSomething();
}
```

However, as said, this does solve the problem but not the question.