# Infinite scroll page number

Tags: jquery

On this guys [blog](http://alex.clst.org/dbd/) he's using infinite scroll and it's appending the page number to the url so when you click on a story and go back, you start off where you were.

I'm using infinite scrolling on a website I'm developing just now but I can't figure out how this is done, it's not a function built into the plugin.

I'm not using jetpack, I'm using the [standalone plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/)

Also, if I append a page number to my local installation like this

```
http://localhost:8888/page/2
```

Then scroll down, it loads in the next set of posts, then it breaks and doesn't load in anymore posts.

Is there a way to append the page number as more posts are loaded in with infinite scroll?

Comment: the script used in jetpack (and the site you linked) and the plugin you're using are two entirely different scripts, so it's not a matter of simply enabling it. [download jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) and search inside the file `infinity.js` for `history.pushState` to see exactly where the page URL is manipulated.

Comment: Ah, and it seems that even with jetpack in dev mode I can't use infinite scroll on a local site?

I was going to use HTML5 history API to append the name of the current post in view, but when using the back button it always just shows the newest posts and you have to scroll down again to load in the ones you were previously viewing, so that's out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [original answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/get-page-number-with-infinite-scroll/89967#89967).

To sum it up briefly:

- Build a custom plugin
- Register a custom script
- Localize this script to add the data from `$GLOBALS['wp_query']` - `numberposts`, `posts_per_page` and `found_posts` in it.
- Write a custom event handler that triggers when the infinite scroll function runs.

Here's a [link to the original script in the SVN trunk](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/infinite-scroll/tags/2.6.2/js/front-end/jquery.infinitescroll.dev.js).